# Vulcanized Polymer app looks weird after compiling with Crosswalk

Tags: android, cordova, polymer, crosswalk-runtime, vulcanize

I have a simple Polymer HTML app that I want to compile into a apk using the Cordova Crosswalk project. The app is fully functional when running on a webserver. It also works as expected after being vulcanized.

But after using Crosswalk to make the APK and installing it on my phone it breaks. The slide-out menu is rendered below everything else. The radio buttons doesn't register a click and the ripple effect gets stuck around it. Normal buttons seem to work as intended. The app also has a white border at the edges.

I suspect it is somehow caused by using Vulcanize and Crosswalk. I'm unable to try it without Vulcanize as I get an error that seems to be pretty common and the only solution I found was Vulcanize. http://zclark.github.io/2014/11/26/polymer-crosswalk.html

I tried to use the --inline-scripts command while vulcanizing but that resulted with just a white blank page instead.

Anyone knows what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That must be css/javascript talking, that gets picked up.
There is an easier way if you have used android studio, 
just create a webview and load ur html with loadurl. see details.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. I'm using Brackets but I will check my css and JS to see if I can find anything weird.